# Can I use different sized steppers for different axes?

Tags: diy-3d-printer, stepper, nema-17, tmc2209

So basically, I have 3 different types of steppers.

- A NEMA 23 stepper for the Z-axis,
- a good quality NEMA 17 for Y-axis and
- another lower quality NEMA 17 for X-axis.

This setup should work right?. I'm using TMC2209's stepper drivers and all are well within the drivers rated phase current limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each axis is fine using a different stepper size and/or quality. You will still need to tune their operating current and steps/mm for each of course. Make sure your motor mounts fit too.

Where it might become challenging is if you wanted two different steppers on the SAME axis. As in, a NEMA17 + NEMA23 for a dual Z axis. I don't think this is what you intend though.